# Cursor doesn't move after setting formatterValue in input. React, Android devices

Tags: reactjs, input, numbers, mask

I have a `tel` input with a mask.

```
value={this.getFormattedValue(mask)}
```

In some android devices (Samsung galaxy s6/s7), after setting a formatted value, the cursor does not move to the end of a typed number. So, after the mask inserts, for example, value + ")", the cursor moves only to 1 position instead of 2. And we have typed a number is a partly-reversed order.

How can I avoid this issue? I guess I can count a number of created characters by mask and move cursor to this number after editing. But how can I do it elegantly with React?

Thanks for the help.